# jQuery and XML- Failed to reading the remote resource

Tags: jquery, xml

I have problem with xml urls when getting their feed using custom code.
I have tried to understand which solution about it in google and here,but I can't understand perfectly to solve that,so I need your help,thanks.

The error i got " Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.straitstimes.com/news/sport/rss.xml. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)."

So, how to implement the solution for my code below?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.straitstimes.com/news/sport/rss.xml',
    contentType: "text/xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        $(xml).find("item").each(function () {
            var title = $(this).find("title").text();
            var description = $(this).find("description").text();
            var linkUrl = $(this).find("link_url").text();
            var link = "<a href='" + linkUrl + "' target='_blank'>Read More<a>";
            $('#feedContainer').append('<article><h3>'+title+'</h3><p>'+description+link+'</p>');
        });
    },
        error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){  
        console.log(xhr.status);          
        console.log(thrownError);
     }
});
```

Comment: Since this is a cross domain request, check whether the feed accepts JSONP

Comment: I agree for your suggestion,but I have to use XML for this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using YQL console we can overcome this cross origin request... Just changed the URL and removed contentType.. Check out this jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/1rmk8z4k/

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from xml where url ="http://www.thestar.com.my/RSS/News/Education/"',

success: function (xml) {
    $(xml).find("item").each(function () {
        var title = $(this).find("title").text();
        var description = $(this).find("description").text();
        var linkUrl = $(this).find("link_url").text();
        var link = "<a href='" + linkUrl + "' target='_blank'>Read More<a>";
        $('#feedContainer').append('<article><h3>'+title+'</h3><p>'+description+link+'</p>');
    });
},
    error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){  
    console.log(xhr.status);          
    console.log(thrownError);
 }
});
```